# Mhtml is Saved as .html extension in chrome and edge. how to fix it?

Tags: google-chrome, html, microsoft-edge, save-as

> [image]

Like the photo above, when i try to save web as to .mhtml file, It dosen't save .mhtml. it just save to as .html. So when i save web to .mhtml, I manually change file extension html to mhtml. How can i fix this problem?

Comment: It works for me. Does it work better when running Chrome in Incognito mode?

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: Upvote this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1057469&q=mhtml&can=2

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, proper MHTML support only really exists in Internet Explorer. You can add a Chrome extension which will help you https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-as-mhtml/ahgakckdonjmnpnegjcamhagackmjpei?hl=en